# Intermittent dependency injection failure

Tags: c#, azure, dependency-injection, azure-functions

I am seeing the following intermittent exception locally when trying to resolve a service within a .net core 2.1 azure function app.  It only seems to happen when multiple messages are being processed by the function concurrently and it only fails some of the messages.

> 'System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: FunctionOne. Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration' while attempting to activate 'XXX.Service2'.

When the Service is in the same project as the function then everything works fine.  It is only when I move it into another project that this occurs.  The other project I created is just a simple .net standard 2.0 project with just this service in and a reference to the Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration nuget.

I know that this implementation uses a Service Locator which is an anti pattern but I still want to understand why this exception occurs.

```
[FunctionName("FunctionOne")]
public static void Run(
    [QueueTrigger(_queue, Connection = _storageConnection)]
    string queueItem,
    ILogger trace)
{
    // Startup
    var services = Startup.GetServices();

    // Services
    var service = services.GetService<IService2>();
}
```

```
public static class Startup
{
    public static Func<IServiceProvider> GetServices = CreateServices;

    public static IConfiguration GetConfiguration()
    {
        return new ConfigurationBuilder()
             .AddEnvironmentVariables()
             .Build();
    }

    private static IServiceProvider CreateServices()
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();

        var config = GetConfiguration();

        services
            .AddSingleton(config)
            .AddSingleton<IService2, Service2>();

        return services.BuildServiceProvider();
    }
}
```

```
public class Service2 : IService2
{
    public Service2(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
    }
}
```

```
public interface IService2
{
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a 'feature' that was introduced with version 2.0.12408.0 of the runtime. It does not happen with 2.0.12382.0.

Comment: This is not using the DI feature, but just a static class and method building a service provider and using that directly in the function. We'll soon have documentation providing guidance on how to do the above using the actual feature. The code you have above doesn't use anything that is Functions specific.

Comment: Yes, this doesn't use the DI feature but regardless the exception only occurs in the newer version of the runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Try injecting it as an IConfigurationRoot instead of IConfiguration:

```
public HomeController(IConfigurationRoot configuration
    , IService2 service)
{
    _mailService = service;
    _to = configuration["emailAddress.Support"];
}
```

In this case, the line

```
services.AddSingleton(provider => Configuration);
```

is equivalent to

```
services.AddSingleton<IConfigurationRoot>(provider => Configuration);
```

because the Configuration property on the class is declared as such, and injection will be done by matching whatever type it was registered as. We can replicate this pretty easily, which might make it clearer:

try this and see if it helps.